# How to randomize parameter of instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to have a different count of cube for each array. ive tried using the attribute statistic, random value and changing the seed value but each array still have the same amount of cube[image]

Comment: I only can tell you why it doesn't work but not how to fix it. The *Random Value* node gives you just one random value (=solid connection line) because you use a single ID for it (*Max* is just a single value). What you want is a field of 6 values (=dotted connection line). The bad thing is that the *Count* input of the *Mesh Line* does not accept field values, only a single value. In consequence, it doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 1):

one possible way is doing it like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

it save an index for each point of the instance and it saves the instance index.
Then via a random value based on the instance index all points above that random value will be deleted, so that every column gets a different height.

Comment: i prefer if the solution more direct to the node parameter itself

Comment: with the current state of GN - this is simply not possible, because instances are linked copies and cannot have different properties except location/scale/rotation and custom attribute (values).